# How to check for internet connection without having to refresh my whole page

Tags: javascript, refresh

I want the following function to be called every x seconds, so I don't have to refresh my page.

```
var rq = new XMLHttpRequest();
rq.open('GET', "SAME DOMAIN ADDRESS", true);
rq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(rq.readyState === 4) {
        if(rq.status === 200) {
      clearTimeout(xmlHttpTimeout); 
window.location.href = "Tracker.html"; // if internet connection found, redirect.
        } else {
        }
    }
};
rq.send(""); 
var xmlHttpTimeout=setTimeout(ajaxTimeout,5000);
function ajaxTimeout(){
   rq.abort();
// IF no internet connection found, call this whole javascript function/code AGAIN in 5 seconds! to check for internet connection
}
```

Basically, I want to check for internet connection without having to refresh my whole page - and if there is, then redirect to `Tracker.html`

Comment: AJAX - May The Force be with you!

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Read about it.

Comment: Of course, by the time that you *know* the answer, the actual answer may have changed. I.e. the connection could be coming up and down randomly, so the redirect may still fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `navigator.onLine` is true or false.

Comment: Wow! This is powerful, never heard of it. THX!

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use `setTimeout`:

```
function callMe() {
  // Some Code
  setTimeout(callMe, 1000);
}

callMe();
```

Your code will look like that:

```
var rq = new XMLHttpRequest();

rq.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(rq.readyState === 4) {
    if(rq.status === 200) {
      window.location.href = "Tracker.html"; // if internet connection found, redirect.
    } else {
      setTimeout(rq.send, 5000);
    }
  }
};

rq.send();
```

If you want to check if the client is connected you can also use the new online and offline events described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events).

Comment: So the question is...how do I 'insert' the javascript code above into the callMe function? I'm asking because, there's more functions inside the above code.....

Comment: I've edited my code, but I strongly suggest you to use navigator.onLine unless you don't have to support older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

An ajax solution will only work on the same domain. However on the same domain you will probably not need to test whether the server is online. With navigator.onLine it will indicate whether the internet is accessible however still the appropriate server can be unreachable.

The trick is to try to load an image of the target server and on error then retry after 5 seconds. And when the image has been loaded successfully then a redirect could be done.

```
<html>
  <header>
  </header>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var img = new Image();
    var ping = function() { img.src = "http://www.somedomain.com/valid_image.jpg"; }
    ping();

    img.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log('error');
      setTimeout(function() {
        ping();
      }, 5000);
    }

    img.onload = function(e) {
      console.log('YES');
      window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"; 
    }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```